# Is it possible to look at the output of the previous row of a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

This is the question: Is it possible to look at the outputs, what has been selected, from the previous row of a running SQL query in Postgres?

I know that `lag` exists to look at the inputs, the "from" of the query. I also know that a CTE, subquery or lateral join can solve most issues of this kind. But I think the problem I'm facing genuinely requires a peek at the output of the previous row. Why? Because the output of the current row depends on a constant from a lookup table and the value used too look up that constant is an aggregate of all the previous rows. And if that lookup returns the wrong constant all subsequent rows will be increasingly off from the expected value.

The whole rest of this text is a simplified example based on the problem I'm facing. It should be possible to input it to PostgreSQL 12 and above and play around. I'm terribly sorry that it is as complicated as it is, but I think it is the most simple I can make it while still retaining the core issue: lookup in lookup table based on an aggregate from all previous rows as well as the fact that the "inventory" that's being tracked is modeled as a series of transactions of two discrete types.

The database itself exists to keep track of multiple fish farms, or cages full of fish. Fish can be moved/transferred from between these farms and the farms are fed about daily. Why not just carry the aggregate as a field in the table? Because it should be possible to switch out the lookup table after the season is over, to adjust it to better match with reality.

```
-- A listing of all groups of fish ever grown.
create table farms (
    id             bigserial primary key,
    start          timestamp not null,
    stop           timestamp
);

insert into farms
    (id, start)
values (
    1, '2021-02-01T13:37'
);

-- A transfer of fish from one odling to another.
-- If the source is null the fish is transferred from another fishery outside our system.
-- If the destination is null the fish is being slaughtered, removed from the system.
create table transfers (
    source           bigint    references farms(id),
    destination      bigint    references farms(id),
    timestamp        timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    total_weight_g   bigint    not null constraint positive_nonzero_total_weight_g check (total_weight_g > 0),
    average_weight_g bigint    not null constraint positive_nonzero_average_weight_g check (average_weight_g > 0),
    number_fish      bigint    generated always as (total_weight_g / average_weight_g) stored
);

insert into transfers
    (source, destination, timestamp, total_weight_g, average_weight_g)
values
    (null, 1, '2021-02-01T16:38',  5,   5),
    (null, 1, '2021-02-15T16:38',  500, 500);


-- Transactions of fish feed into a farm.
create table feedings (
    id             bigserial primary key,
    growth_table   bigint    not null,
    farm           bigint    not null references farms(id),
    amount_g       bigint    not null constraint positive_nonzero_amunt_g check (amount_g > 0),
    timestamp      timestamp not null
);

insert into feedings
    (farm, growth_table, amount_g, timestamp)
values
    (1, 1, 1,  '2021-02-02T13:37'),
    (1, 1, 1,  '2021-02-03T13:37'),
    (1, 1, 1,  '2021-02-04T13:37'),
    (1, 1, 1,  '2021-02-05T13:37'),
    (1, 1, 1,  '2021-02-06T13:37'),
    (1, 1, 1,  '2021-02-07T13:37');


create view combined_feed_and_transfer_history as
with transfer_history as (
  select timestamp, destination as farm, total_weight_g, average_weight_g, number_fish
    from transfers as deposits
   where deposits.destination = 1 -- TODO: This view only works for one farm, fix that.
  union all
  select timestamp, source as farm, -total_weight_g, -average_weight_g, -number_fish
    from transfers as withdrawals
   where withdrawals.source = 1
)
select timestamp, farm, total_weight_g, number_fish, average_weight_g, null as growth_table
from transfer_history
union all
select timestamp, farm, amount_g, 0 as number_fish, 0 as average_weight_g, growth_table
from feedings
order by timestamp;


-- Conversion tables from feed to gained weight.
create table growth_coefficients (
    growth_table                   bigserial        not null,
    average_weight_g               bigint           not null constraint positive_nonzero_weight                 check (average_weight_g     >  0),
    feed_conversion_rate           double precision not null constraint positive_foderkonverteringsfaktor       check (feed_conversion_rate >= 0),
    primary key(growth_table, average_weight_g)
);

insert into growth_coefficients
    (average_weight_g, feed_conversion_rate, growth_table)
values
    (5.00,0.10,1),
    (10.00,10.00,1),
    (20.00,1.30,1),
    (50.00,1.31,1),
    (100.00,1.32,1),
    (300.00,1.36,1),
    (600.00,1.42,1),
    (1000.00,1.50,1),
    (1500.00,1.60,1),
    (2000.00,1.70,1),
    (2500.00,1.80,1),
    (3000.00,1.90,1),
    (4000.00,2.10,1),
    (5000.00,2.30,1);


-- My current solution is a bad one. It does a CTE that sums over all events but does not account
-- for the feed conversion rate. That means that the average weight used too look up the feed
-- conversion rate will diverge more and more from reality the further into the season time goes.
-- This is why it is important to look at the output, the average weight, of the previous row.

-- We start by summing up all the transfer and feed events to get a rough average_weight_g.
with estimate as (
    select
        timestamp,
        farm,
        total_weight_g as transaction_size_g,
        growth_table,
        sum(total_weight_g) over (order by timestamp)                                              as sum_weight_g,
        sum(number_fish)    over (order by timestamp)                                              as sum_number_fish,
        sum(total_weight_g) over (order by timestamp) / sum(number_fish) over (order by timestamp) as average_weight_g
    from
        combined_feed_and_transfer_history
)
select
    timestamp,
    sum_number_fish,
    transaction_size_g as trans_g,
    sum_weight_g,
    closest_lookup_table_weight.average_weight_g as lookup_g,
    converted_weight_g as conv_g,
    sum(converted_weight_g) over (order by timestamp)                   as sum_conv_g,
    sum(converted_weight_g) over (order by timestamp) / sum_number_fish as sum_average_g
from
    estimate
    join lateral ( -- We then use this estimated_average_weight to look up the closest constant in the growth coefficient table.
      (select gc.average_weight_g - estimate.average_weight_g as diff, gc.average_weight_g from growth_coefficients gc where gc.average_weight_g >= estimate.average_weight_g order by gc.average_weight_g asc  limit 1)
        union all
        (select estimate.average_weight_g - gc.average_weight_g as diff, gc.average_weight_g from growth_coefficients gc where gc.average_weight_g <= estimate.average_weight_g order by gc.average_weight_g desc limit 1)
        order by diff
        limit 1
    ) as closest_lookup_table_weight
    on true
    join lateral ( -- If the historical event is a feeding we need to lookup the feed conversion rate.
        select case when growth_table is null then 1
                  else (select feed_conversion_rate
                        from   growth_coefficients gc
                        where  gc.growth_table     = growth_table
                        and    gc.average_weight_g = closest_lookup_table_weight.average_weight_g)
             end
    ) as growth_coefficient
    on true
    join lateral (
        select feed_conversion_rate * transaction_size_g as converted_weight_g
    ) as converted_weight_g
    on true;
```

At the very bottom is my current "solution". With the above example data the `sum_conv_g` should end up being 5.6, but due to the aggregate being used as the lookup not accounting for the conversion rate the `sum_conv_g` ends up 45.2 instead.

One idea I had was if there perhaps something like query-local variables one could use to store the `sum_average_g` between rows? There's always the escape hatch of just querying out the transactions to my generic programming language Clojure and solving it there, but it would be neat if it could be solved entirely within the database.

Comment: The typical solution is to compute the values in two steps, using a subquery as the first step. In the first step you compute the value with joins, aggregates, lateral queries, etc. and name it using `AS`; then in the outer query you can peek at it using `LAG()`.

Comment: You seem pretty well versed with CTEs, lateral queries and window functions. It shouldn't be too difficult to separate the query into the two-step solution. If you cannot, I can try helping. What's wrong in the current result? See fiddle at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6qHEy5AB4hTfCzXLMH7uZc/0

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me! The problem is that separating the query into a two-step solution is what I think I have done, but I'm probably missing som detail that makes all the difference. The example data was a bad pick, take a look at this instead: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6qHEy5AB4hTfCzXLMH7uZc/2 In this example the `sum_conv_g` should end up being 5.6, but due to the aggregate being used as the lookup not accounting for the conversion rate the `sum_conv_g` ends up 45.2 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to formulate a recursive subquery. I posted a simplified version of this question over at the DBA SE and got the answer there. The answer to that question can be found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/305939/152338) and can be expanded to this more complicated question, though I would wager that no one will ever have the interest to do that.